# applying gabor filter to an images

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am a very much new to image processing.I want to know how to apply gabor filter on an image with 12 different orientations say 0,15,30,45 to 165.I want to apply this gabor filter for 12 orientations and output of each orientation has to be displayed.My input is a image of retina and output of orientation should be fine tuned image of retina after applying gabor filter.How do i do it?

```
 %code for gabor filter                
 I = getimage();         
 I=I(:,:,2);    
 lambda  = 8;    
theta   = 0;    
psi     = [0 pi/2];    
gamma   = 0.5;    
 bw      = 1;    
 N       = 12;    
img_in = im2double(I);    
%img_in(:,:,2:3) = [];  % discard redundant channels, it's gray anyway    
 img_out = zeros(size(img_in,1), size(img_in,2), N);        
 for n=1:N         
        gb = gabor_fn(bw,gamma,psi(1),lambda,theta)...          
         + 1i * gabor_fn(bw,gamma,psi(2),lambda,theta);     
         % gb is the n-th gabor filter         
         img_out(:,:,n) = imfilter(img_in, gb, 'symmetric');          
        % filter output to the n-th channel       
        %theta = theta + 2*pi/N;          
        theta = 15 * n;   % i wrote this because my angles are multiples of 15       
        % next orientation           
 end 

 figure(1);           
 imshow(img_in);                  
 title('input image');                    
 figure(2);            
 img_out_disp = sum(abs(img_out).^2, 3).^0.5;        
 %default superposition method, L2-norm        
 img_out_disp = img_out_disp./max(img_out_disp(:));           
 % normalize        
 imshow(img_out_disp);         
 title('gabor output, L-2 super-imposed, normalized');
```

my input image is 
[image]

and my output image is
[image]

how do i orient my image in 12 different direction by applying gabor filter

I am supposed to get a ouput of a retinal image but i am getting my output image as

[image]

Comment: What you are getting is the visualization of the Gabor Filter you are using. You need to apply this filter to the retina image to get the image you want.

Comment: oh oh k sir...i will try doing it...thanks a lot sir

Comment: sir, how can i apply this filter to retinal image. i tried using conv2 function but it din work any other method

Comment: the last image is the filter's image right?

Comment: yes sir ..its the filter image..now i want to impose this image on my original image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add these two lines:

```
...
% gb is the n-th gabor filter 
img_out(:,:,n) = imfilter(img_in, gb, 'symmetric');   
figure;
imshow(img_out(:,:,n));
...
```

Comment: sir i had tried the same..that did not give me proper output.i want my output image which i have uploaded to be in 2 different orientation. and also i think the output could be obtained by super imposition of two images that is by my original image and img_out of my for loop...i dont knw whether i am right i am just guessing it

Comment: you wrote 12 different orientation in the question. Can you specify in the question what you already tried and what didn't work? Did you write the code you attached yourself? because you are actually creating all the images you need, you just have to show them separately.

Comment: sure sir. i will edit my question..and sir i have tried this program i am not getting proper output image as my output image

Comment: siri am getting the visualization output.i want to impose these 12 different outputs on my original image how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your question that you want to apply gabor filter 12 time and each time with specified direction(theta) right?                                to do this --> before for loop write this ----> 
...

```
responses = {}; % to save each response from filter.
```

and after filtering your image convolve it like this ---->
...

```
response =  conv2(img_in,gb,'same');
```

...

then get your amplitudes like this --->
...

```
realpart = real(response);
imagpart = imag(response);
response = sqrt(realpart.^2 + imagpart.^2);
```

...

replace ---> img_out(:,:,n)
   with this ---->
...

```
responses = cat(1,responses,response);
```

this code will save your responses from each filter to a cell
and if you want to see the responses just do this 
...

```
X = responses{1}; % or 2 or 3...
```

this link will give a better information about gabor filter
 http://matlabserver.cs.rug.nl/edgedetectionweb/web/edgedetection_params.html

hope this will help you.
best regard.

Comment: Please, edit your post correctly, it is practically unreadable now.

Comment: Ander Biguri i edited my post and made it readable, thank you.